# @XmlElementWrapper not taken into account in XML/REST Spring webservice

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to give custom names to the xml root element and to list elements.
But the annotations don't work.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestRsp {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "persons")
    @XmlElement(name = "pax")
    private List<Person> persons;
}

public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String age;
}
```

Usage:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @RequestMapping("/test")
   public TestRsp test() {
      //...
      return rsp;
   }
}
```

Result:

```
<TestRsp> <!-- should be named "test" -->
   <persons>
     <persons> <!-- should be named "pax" -->
       <name />
       <age />
     </persons>
     <persons>
        //...
     </persons>
   </persons>
</TestRsp>
```

So my xml annotations are not picked up. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@JsonProperty` annotation.

It should look something like thit:

```
@JsonProperty("test")
```

EDIT 1:

Try annotating the getter of the fields that you want to change like so:

```
@XmlElement(name="someName")
```

EDIT 2:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="persons")
public class Root {


    private List<String> someList;


    @XmlElement(name="pax")
    public List<String> getSomeList() {
        return someList;
    }

    public void setSomeList(List<String> someList) {
        this.someList = someList;
    } 

    public Root(String numValue,List<String> someListValue) {
        this();
        this.number = numValue;
        this.someList = someListValue;  
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Root() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Maybe this will provide:

```
 <persons>
    <pax>FOO</pax>
    <pax>BAR</pax>
 </persons>
```

EDIT 3:

Maybe if you want to make your solution works you need to add a file called ***jaxb.properties*** in with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: Strange, this creates nested lists `<test><test></test>...</test>`. Why? Because I want to output xml. And more important: how can I name the list *wrapper* element different than the elements itself (similar to the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation)?

Comment: Well `@JsonPRoperty` is just for properties actually not working for annotating classes that is why I believe it behaves so strange (nested lists) . So it will solve the problem with the `pax` named param. I am just checking for solution on class level.

Comment: But `@JsonProperty` renames both the wrapper element and the list element itself. How can I name them independently?

Comment: Hmm can you try with EDIT 1.

Comment: Also EDIT 2 and EDIT 3 added hope they help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I have to use `@JacksonXml*` annotations instead:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "test")
public class TestRsp {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "persons")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "pax")
    @JsonProperty(name = "persons")
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```